# How do I auto-fill multiple cells based on a value chosen in a drop down list in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I been trying and trying to create a drop down list to which when I click on a value in it, it will auto-fill the cells next to it.

The data that needs to be autofilled is pulled from another tab which is pulled by import range (since this data will be in a "Master staffing overview")

I managed to do so, but it won't copy to some of the rows and for some reason I have 1 row (which is working) that shows no "#ref!" or "#NA" which I ofc would prefer for the rows not to show. But most important is that I can copy the formatting/function easily to the others row without having to change the range for each column for each row.

I made a copy of the sheet for showcasing it. Anyone who knows an easy fix to this? (perhaps a different function?)

Link for sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ygt4UX5sx4naIrTR57ksc_VzAC5VyuyiB9ibwxspuJ4/edit?usp=sharing